# Accessibility: Section 508 vs WCAG

Tags: accessibility, section508, wcag

My company is based in the UK, but is involved in a website for a US based company.

Our website follows the WC3 standards (WCAG 2.0) for accessibility. In terms of the USA does anyone know what the law is on accessibility? (I've heard of section 508 - is this something to look at?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, our laws in the U.S. are not near as stringent as around the world (I wish they were).  But the W3C is a good place to start, see their page http://www.w3.org/WAI/ and yes 508 applies to federal locations, see [http://www.section508.gov/...](http://www.section508.gov/index.cfm?ID=3&FuseAction=Content) for information on these laws.

Answer (score 0):

508 is the US Government's spelled out accessibility standards that are required for any and all government agencies (excluding national security related ones). Basically, if you're trying to pitch your product to get a government contract, it has to comply with those standards.
That said, if your page conforms to WCAG A and AA, you're probably pretty close to 508 compliance already.